# Txt file overwrite in Python

Tags: python

i am having struggles with the infile.write function... it keeps on overwriting the data of the .txt file... help!

```
Num = input("Number: ")
fNm = input("First Name: ")
lNm = input("Last Name: ")
infile = open("pInfo.txt","w")
infile.write("Number"+"\t\t"+"Name\n")
infile.write("Num+"\t\t\t+fNm+" "+lNm+"\n")
```

.txt file:

before putting test 2:

```
Number          Name
Test            test Test
```

after putting test 2:

```
Number          Name
Test2           test2 Test2
```

Comment: If you want to append to the file use this syntax `open("pInfo.txt","a")`

Comment: yep it worked! thanks...

Answer (score 1):

To append to the file:

```
infile = open("pInfo.txt","a")
```